# Script tag nested in SVG tag directly embedded in the HTML causes SVG to show up blank

Tags: javascript, safari, svg

I'm trying to nest a script tag inside an SVG tag, but the SVG shows up blank in Safari.

The following fiddle works in FF 15.0, Chrome 21.0, and IE9, but not in Safari 5 on Windows.

http://jsfiddle.net/5rnbU/4/

```
<svg height="320" width="320" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
    <script >
    setTimeout("run()",1000);

    function run(){
        var e = document.getElementById("rect");
        console.log(e);
        setTimeout("run()",1000);
    }
    </script>
    <rect id="rect" ry="6" rx="6" fill="silver" height="320" width="320" y="0" x="0"/>
</svg>
```

The SVG is embedded directly into the HTML. If the script tag is removed, this works and if you inspect the SVG you will see that the script tag is enclosing the following SVG elements. Why? What are some workarounds?

Comment: Perhaps safari needs type="text/javascript" as an attribute on the script element.

Comment: I've tried that. It still shows up blank.

Comment: Could it be looking for `script` in the SVG namespace and not finding it, thanks to `xmlns` appearing in the `svg` tag? Not sure if `script` exists in the SVG namespace or not. Anyway, does it work if you move the script outside of the `svg` element?

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle need you write javascript code in the javascript panel. you write javascript code in the html panel and JSFiddle cannot run it rightly.

the right way is:

http://jsfiddle.net/5rnbU/7/

write html in html panel:

```
<svg height="320" width="320" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
    <rect id="rect" ry="6" rx="6" fill="silver" height="320" width="320" y="0" x="0"/>
</svg>
```

write javascript in javascript panel:

```
setTimeout("run()",1000);

function run(){
    var e = document.getElementById("rect");
    console.log(e);
    setTimeout("run()",1000);
}
```

Don't write them all in html panel.

Comment: I am looking to get the scripts nested into the SVG itself. It's likely Safari just doesn't like the script being there and I have to live with it.